# No visual studio installed but programData/package cache is filling up with files

Tags: windows, windows-server-2019

How can I prevent files from being created in programData/package.

I do not have visual studio installed but programData/package cache is filling up with files.

I checked and found that I should not delete those files but I'm not sure why I am getting those files if there is no Visual Studio installed.
I tried this command "%ProgramFiles(x86)%\Microsoft Visual Studio\Installer\vs_installer.exe" --nocache
This fails as there is no visual studio.

How do I get rid of these files?

Comment: Are you building any .net projects? Building does not need VS, but still downloads packages.

Comment: No .net projects...it is our tableau server and that is all it is running.

Comment: Can you specify exactly what folder you mean? Maybe it's something very different.

Comment: The specific folder is:
C:\ProgramData\Package Cache\

In there are many folders with dates from 04/13/2021 through to 02/16/2022
If I look into one of the large folders it contains Tableau setup files cab1, cab2, and the file tableau-setup-tsm-tableau-2021-4.22.0101.... which is a windows installer file.
These files add up to over 2GB of space and I'd like to remove them. 
It's hard to tell if they are still needed or not.

Comment: Looks like some installer packages, yes. I do not know who creates them, but could also be Windows Update. Maybe the question would be better asked at server fault, because it's not about programming.